# Content publishing using DXA with Web 8.5

Tags: dxa, publishing, topology-manager, web8.5, deployer-conf

We have been asked to perform a quick POC (Proof of concept) using DXA with Web 8.5.  Due to infrastructure limitation we want to publish the content to file system (DB is not available), as POC will be done for a static website. We have following queries.

1. In DXA implementation is it mandatory to publish everything to Broker DB?
2. If we want to publish to file system where exactly we have to change it, cd_deployer_config?
3. How Topology manager uses cd_deployer_config and cd_storage_config?
4. Is Topology Manager having it's own set of cd_deployer_config and cd_storage_config? if yes where ?

Comment: What does "DB not available" mean? What are you using for CM and Topology Manager DBs, then?

Comment: And what does "POC will be done for static website" mean? It seems a bit weird to me to use a Dynamic Delivery architecture (which DXA uses) to serve a static website.

Comment: @Rick Pannekoek : Broker Database/Content data store is not available.  Yes I will remove the word static from the question, all in all we want to perform a POC using DXA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In DXA implementation is it mandatory to publish everything to Broker DB?

Yes, this is required. You could change DXA code to work around this, but it's probably going to be a lot of trouble.

> If we want to publish to file system where exactly we have to change it, cd_deployer_config?

cd_storage_conf for the deployer. As said above, this will **very likely** not work.

> How Topology manager uses cd_deployer_config and cd_storage_config?

Topology Manager runs on the Content Manager side, it does not use deployer nor storage.

> Is Topology Manager having it's own set of cd_deployer_config and cd_storage_config? if yes where ?

See above.

Seems like you're exploring both Web 8 *and* DXA, and therefore I'd recommend getting some deep information on 8 before you jump into this. We changed *a lot*, especially in CD, and don't think you can just wing it - there's a learning curve.

I would also recommend using [this script](https://github.com/NunoLinhares/Web-8.5-Quick-Install/) to set up your first environment - it will save you the hassle of having to understand Topology Manager for your first configuration, and it deploys the DXA too.

Answer (score 4):

1. As per DXA documentation , yes it is mandatory to publish it to database,
   [SDL Docs](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v7/GUID-6D3337B6-FC47-479A-A38B-6AF3C53B9A51)
2. Not valid, as it is not possible to publish to file system with out of the box DXA
3. Topology manager maintains a link between CM and CD using a new Microservice called discovery.svc where we configure the deployer capabilities
4. You can see the Topology Manager's CDEnvironment configuration information using the following powershell command,
   Get-ttmCDEnvironment